# iOS devices cannot connect to hostapd wireless Access Point

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, network-manager, hostapd

I've managed to setup an AP on PC running Ubuntu 12.04 with a wireless adapter with a RTL8192CU chipset. The PC is connected to internet via `wlan0` and the access point is set up on `wlan1`.

I can connect to the AP with a windows laptop and an Android device, but I cant connect with an iOS device. When I try to I get the following output from the PC running hostapd:

```
wlan1: STA 88:c6:63:ec:ed:06 IEEE 802.11: authenticated
wlan1: STA 88:c6:63:ec:ed:06 IEEE 802.11: associated (aid 1)
AP-STA-CONNECTED 88:c6:63:ec:ed:06
wlan1: STA 88:c6:63:ec:ed:06 RADIUS: starting accounting session 546340C4-00000006
wlan1: STA 88:c6:63:ec:ed:06 WPA: pairwise key handshake completed (RSN)

AP-STA-DISCONNECTED 88:c6:63:ec:ed:06
wlan1: STA 88:c6:63:ec:ed:06 IEEE 802.11: disassociated
wlan1: STA 88:c6:63:ec:ed:06 IEEE 802.11: deauthenticated due to inactivity
```

It seems as if it is timing out, I say that because it hangs on the 5th line (pairwise key handshake) around ten seconds then continues to be disconnected. This only happens on the iOS devices, android smartphone and windows pc connects without problems.

Here is the `hostapd.conf`

```
interface=wlan1
driver=nl80211
ssid=myssid
hw_mode=g
channel=6
# tried with and without the following lines, android & windows connects iOS can't
ieee801x=0
eap_server=0
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wmm_enabled=0
wpa=2
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
wpa_passphrase=mypassphrase
```

Does iOS devices need additional/specific configurations to be made on `hostapd.conf`? Or is this a problem with the wireless adapter? Any suggestions?

PS I didn't include any other information than the `hostapd.conf` since I can't even connect to the AP I assume this is a hostapd problem.

Answer (score 1):

I tried with another network card using an atheros chipset (Atheros AR9271) and it solved my issue.

I came across [this post on comments.gmane.org](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.drivers.hostap/30501) emailed the poster and he also said he changed his network card to ALFA Network AWUS036NH to get around this issue, apparently.